# Rails_admin undefined method 'field' with has many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm having problems with the rails admin gem & has many associations.  I keep receiving this error: "undefined method `field' for #" when visiting my /admin panel for the first time.  If I refresh the page it loads the page and seems to work correctly.  My model/section.rb is the following:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :course
has_many :quizzes, foreign_key: "lesson_id"
has_many :lessons, foreign_key: "section_id"#, :inverse_of => :sections
accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons

rails_admin do
   create do
    field :course do
      default_value do
        Course.last.id
      end
     end
    field :title
  end

edit do
  field :course do
      default_value do
        Course.last.id
      end
  end
  field :title
end
end

 rails_admin do
   configure :lessons do
     field :title  # This is the line that is giving the error
     field :body
     field :image

    end
end

end
```

My models/lesson.rb looks like:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :section #, foreign_key: "section_id"#, :inverse_of => :lessons
 has_many :posts, foreign_key: "lesson_id"
 has_one :quiz, :inverse_of => :lesson
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz
```

The error appears on the field :title under configure :lessons.  I'm getting this error with all my models that have has many associations.  Refreshing the page (which needs to be done about 5 / 6 times) shows the 
     mount_uploader :image, PictureUploader
    end